# Content-Length vs complete-length

Tags: http, specifications

I have a case where I am uploading a file and I know the final size once the upload is complete and provide this information when someone is requesting the file while the upload is still in progress.

My problem is **range** requests vs **non range** request and how to handle the resource size.

In the case of **non range** request I always set `Content-Length` to the *expected/final size* of the resource and let the server tail the file.

In the case of **range** request I set the `*/{complete-length}` to the *current size* of the resource and the server returns the current payload **without** tailing the file.

What I'm unsure of is whether this is spec compliant?

In terms of **non range** request the [spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#header.content-length) says:

> the Content-Length indicates the **size** of the selected representation

While in terms of range request the [spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7233.html#header.content-range) says:

> The complete-length in a 416 response indicates the **current length** of the selected representation.

So the question here is whether the spec means that these two are the same or not. My current implementation assumes they are not the same, i.e:

- `Content-Length` is the final/expected size of the resource
- `complete-length` is the current size of the resource